# Which was The Phantom Menace movie gross, $1027+ millions or $924+ millions?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace, production

According to

[List of highest grossing films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_highest-grossing_films)

*Star Wars: Episode I – The Phantom Menace gross was $1027 millions.*

But according to

[Star Wars: Episode I - The Phantom Menace](https://www.boxofficemojo.com/release/rl2742257153/)

*Star Wars: Episode I – The Phantom Menace gross was $924,305,084.*

Which was The Phantom Menace movie gross, $1027+ millions or $924+ millions?

Comment: DVD sales, maybe?

Comment: As far as I understand, both links lists box office and ignore merchandising, home video (dvd), etc.

Comment: Original box office vs. re-releases?  Inflation-adjusted vs. not?  How is exchange accounted for?

Comment: Seems as if the 2012 3D release was included in the higher number.

Comment: This seems to be the version Wikipedia used for the higher number. Since it's shortly after the 3D release, they may have separated that out later. https://web.archive.org/web/20120426003712/http://www.boxofficemojo.com:80/movies/?id=starwars.htm

Comment: I remember that The Phantom Menace was rereleased into theatres a few months after its initial run by popular demand, so that probably adds into it. For what it's worth, the wikipedia article for the movie lists $1.027 billion as its box office gross.

Comment: The boxofficemojo site doesn't say when it was last updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Both answers are technically correct.

For its initial release, *The Phantom Menace* made $924.3 million worldwide, according to the often reliable Box Office Mojo. In 2012, the film was released in 3-D. This brought the total gross for the film to the $1.027 billion.

Here are some citations:

McClintock, Pamela (February 23, 2012). "'Star Wars: Phantom Menace' Crosses $1 Billion Mark at Box Office". The Hollywood Reporter. Archived from the original on October 22, 2013. Retrieved March 28, 2014.

"Star Wars: The Phantom Menace". The Numbers. December 1, 2001. Archived from the original on December 31, 2013. Retrieved July 25, 2006.